# Reduce inequality does not finish

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am trying to show general cases of symmetry of regions.

However, for the following, `Reduce` does not finish:

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, 
    x > 0, ! (RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3), {x}], {x}] \[Xor] 
              RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3), {x}], {-x}])],
    x, Reals]
```

OTOH, if I remove any one of the three conditions (from both parts), e.g.:

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, 
    x > 0, ! (RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[(-2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3), {x}], {x}] \[Xor] 
              RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[(-2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3), {x}], {-x}])],
    x, Reals]
```

it return `False` immediately.

What's happening?

(I know there are other ways to do this, e.g., with `FindInstance`.)

Thanx.

Comment: It results in `False` in several minutes. I'm using 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Timing it with `AbsoluteTiming`. I obtain `{438.211, False}` on a fresh kernel of my comp.

Comment: It also cost me 10 min in Linux to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe other way.

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3), {x}]
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 2 < x < 3) /. 
   x -> -x, {x}]
RegionEqual[reg1, reg2]
```

> `False`

Comment: Thanx! This is helpful. I just noticed that if I pull the exclamation point to outside of the `Reduce`, it also works. But I still would like to know what causes the slowdown with going from two inequalities to three.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround:

```
Reduce[ForAll[x,  x > 0, ! (RegionMember[
   ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 
      2 < x < 3), {x}], {x}] \[Xor] 
  RegionMember[
   ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1 || -2 < x < 0 || 
      2 < x < 3), {x}], {-x}]) // Simplify], x, Reals]
(*False*)
```

Comment: Nice -- thanx! (Still wondering why without the `Simplify` it is stymied.)

Comment: I found other regions, e.g., `-2 < x < 0` -> `-2 < x < -1`, which unfortunately were not solved with this `Simplify` so I will vote in the other answer.